# streaming protocols supported by XBOX

Tags: video-streaming, protocols, xbox360

1) What kind of streaming protocols does XBOX 360 supports?

2) what kind of video formats can be play on XBOX 360?

3) Does H264 and rtsp supported by XBOX 360?

I want to develop some app that will support the video streaming on XBOX 360 platform.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest XDK (20871.6), Microsoft provides a Audio/Video player that you can use easily to stream HD Video.
This takes place in the preview package of the XDK. It should be released and lib-trusted in the next XDK (early december).

You should take a Look at the XDK sample called "XAVSample".

Comment: +1 for bravery and a good answer. You should be careful about posting these details though - you could be in violation of you or your employer's NDA with Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Your first hurdle would be getting the app on the actual platform.  Your only option, short of a direct contract with microsoft, would be the Indie/XNA platform.  XNA games cannot connect to the internet.  So forget that option.

If you manage to score a dev kit and contract with microsoft, you will be looking at h.264, wmv, avi, and even divx as possible options.  There are probably more formats (re: containers) that will depend upon the codec, but the former should be sufficient for any need.